# How to display the google maps in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios6

Hi I am new to iOS programming.My requirement is to display the google maps in iOS6.That means it displays the total world map.Please check the attached image for clarification.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 6.0 and above you have some options:

- Use a `UIWebView` (the google maps rendering 'engine' is not present as before) to load the `maps.google.com` page
- [Use the Google Maps iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) (**Best Option**)
- Use [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/mobile/) and use similar topography rendering to google maps

With the official [Google Maps iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) you can actually add your own map to your app, so this is your best option. The docs have great detailed info on how to setup!

Answer (score 1):

Ideal place to start if you want to display maps in iOS is to check out the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html) (Apple's documentation, you will need a free developer account to access it.) This will show you how to use the MapKit framework.

Note that as of iOS 6 Apple uses their own maps back end rather then Google data. If you just want to display a map, Apple's maps should be sufficient.

If you for some reason need to specifically display a map using Google's data, check out their [iOS Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro).

This is all assuming that you are working on a native Objective C application, not a Phonegap style or web application.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Google Maps SDK for iOS website - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/
But first, you should get an API key here - https://developers.google.com/maps/ios-access