# Google Map on IOS 6

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios6

I have an application that uses maps. In `iOS 5` and below, it used `Google Maps`, but the same application running in `iOS 6` shows `Apple Maps`. However, Apple Maps has some inaccuracies. Is it possible to use `Google Maps` on my `iOS 6` application instead, and if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate. [How to display the google maps in iOS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433949/how-to-display-the-google-maps-in-ios6)

Answer (score 3):

Google has an official SDK available at, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/